# RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required even if I already have 3.10.6 version

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, version

I'm running the installer as described in the guide present in the [LabelPC's GitHub page](https://github.com/bradylowe/labelpc) on Ubuntu 22.04, but I get the following error:

```
Collecting absl-py==0.8.0
  Using cached absl-py-0.8.0.tar.gz (102 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-_yo1tcdy/absl-py_761c46388aa14bfaac46b6c57352037a/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError('Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.')
      RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I don't know how to fix it, since everything is updated.
My Python version is 3.10.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in `abseil-py`. Release 0.8 does Python version comparison [this way](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/blob/pypi-v0.8.0/setup.py#L32-L33). The comparison worked just fine for Pythons up to 3.9 but fails with 3.10+. When `py_version` is `('3', '10')` the comparison returns `False` because in Python `'10'` is less then `'4'`; for strings Python compares `'1'` and `'4'`. (Integer `10` is of course > `4`).

The bug was fixed in commit [d61b0b6](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/commit/d61b0b6bda1902f645e5bbbc3f138c142767befa). Unfortunately `labelpc` [requires](https://github.com/bradylowe/labelpc/blob/d48ba1e0b97acc1405d2ffae3369c0bd2efef2e0/requirements.txt#L1) exact version 0.8. This means that for now `abseil-py` and `labelpc` can be used with Python 2.7 and 3.5-3.9 but not with 3.10+.

Use Python 3.9 and [report](https://github.com/bradylowe/labelpc/issues) the bug.

Answer (score 5):

If reverting to 3.9 is not an option, you can use `--ignore-requires-python` with `pip install` to workaround the problem. It may have other unintended consequences, so test carefully.

Answer (score 1):

the newer Python version has some issues I guess when I was installing some modules gives me some runtime error in Python version 3.11.* something then I resolved this error using the following command.

PS P:\gautam\rasa> python --version
Python 3.10.10
PS P:\gautam\rasa> python -m pip install rasa --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver

Comment: and I think python version 3.10 is a  suitable option newer version has some wheels module issues

Comment: Try to use virtual environments. You can install different python version for that environment.