# pip install error while installing the packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to install these specific packages from the requirements.txt file.

```
absl-py==0.9.0
astunparse==1.6.3
cachetools==4.1.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
gast==0.3.3
google-auth==1.19.2
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.30.0
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
imutils==0.5.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
Keras==2.4.3
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
Markdown==3.2.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.19.0
oauthlib==3.1.0
opencv-python==4.3.0.36
opt-einsum==3.3.0
protobuf==3.12.2
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
PyMySQL==0.10.0
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.6
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
tensorboard==2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.7.0
tensorflow==2.2.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
termcolor==1.1.0
urllib3==1.25.9
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.1.0
```

But I am getting following error from pip:

```
Collecting absl-py==0.9.0
Using cached absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz (104 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in
File "", line 34, in
File "/tmp/pip-install-44e8_ye1/absl-py_ec54182e1d60422f89dec432c95bef6b/setup.py", line 34, in
raise RuntimeError('Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.')
RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

I am using `pip==23.0.1` and `python==3.9.7`.

Would someone help me to figure out this problem??

I also tried by downgrading the pip version and also with latest version of python but still getting the same error message.

I also tried to install packages with '--pre' option as well. No success there, as well.

Comment: This is (was) a bug in their `setup.py` https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/issues/161

Comment: I was wondering that @wim. I saw the version check [here](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/blob/pypi-v0.9.0/setup.py#L33) and wasn't sure if that was going to work as they expected it do. Version 0.9.0 is also quite old anyway (released in 2019).

Comment: @wim That looks like an issue with Python 3.10 (because `"10" < "4"`). It should have worked with Python 3.9

Comment: Are you sure about your Python version? What does `pip --version` say?

Comment: Well, there it is - line 34 https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/blob/pypi-v0.9.0/setup.py#L34  Probably OP is actually on 3.10+

Comment: That's what I thought (either that or they are on <3.4).

Comment: The version of pip which logs this stuff wouldn't run on < 3.4

Comment: @Selcuk, we upgraded pip to its latest version.

Comment: Can you post the full output of `pip --version` command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250610/7976758

Comment: @Selcuk, here is the full output of pip version
`pip 22.3.1 from /home/badmax/dump/dump/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
`
I am running this porject on virtual env.

Comment: Ok so you are on python 3.10 not 3.9.7.