# How solve "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully" in Anaconda, installing rasa

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, rasa

I recently installed Anaconda and Python (3.11.4).
I created my env in Anaconda, and when I tried to install rasa (with "pip install rasa") conda showed me this error.
Please help me

[ERROR when i installed rasa pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YCau.png)

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Eliseo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qo_63x3c\absl-py_16e4b8fcbea9469084883112126934fa\setup.py", line 34, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError('Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.')
      RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried uninstalling Python, and "conda clean --all" in Anaconda Prompt. But it doesn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/11888 It's a bug in `absl-py`; see the detailed description at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250610/7976758 . Try upgrading `absl-py`: `pip install -U absl-py`

Comment: I could solve it, i was to install RASA in Python 3.8!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the official Rasa documentation, it says that it is not compactible with modern Python versions. The most current and 100% compact is installing python3.8

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tar.xz
tar -xf Python-3.8.0.tar.xz
cd Python-3.8.0
./configure --enable-optimizations
make
sudo make altinstall
```

And to create your application.(example on tmp path)

```
cd /tmp/myapp
python3.8 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install rasa
source venv/bin/activate
```

Attention, you may get an outdated pip error

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```