# Error with Python Version, but Python Version is valid?

Tags: python, installation, pip, rasa

I'm getting errors with installing rasa via pip. The error message is shown as below, and it seems to suggest that my Python version isn't applicable, but my Python version is 3.11.3, which is definitely above 3.4. Does anyone have any suggestions on what this could be?

```
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-1.10.2-py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting PyJWT<1.8,>=1.7 (from rasa)
  Using cached PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy<1.4.0,>=1.3.3 in c:\users\ayu\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from rasa) (1.3.24)
Collecting absl-py<0.10,>=0.9 (from rasa)
  Using cached absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz (104 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\albertgranz\App\Local\Temp\pip-install-ctiigi8b\absl-py_f74b78151a764aaaabe5f2a103d08a3d\setup.py", line 34, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError('Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.')
      RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: What is the output of `python --version` command?

Comment: rasa version 1.10.2 is from 2020 and doesn't support Python 3.11. Even the newest version doesn't support 3.11.

Comment: @matszwecja 3.11.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250610/7976758

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required even if I already have 3.10.6 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250036/runtimeerror-python-version-2-7-or-3-4-is-required-even-if-i-already-have-3-10)

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by an incorrect version comparison in the `setup.py` of `absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz` which contains the line

```
py_version = platform.python_version_tuple()
if py_version < ('2', '7') or py_version[0] == '3' and py_version < ('3', '4'):
  raise RuntimeError('Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.')
```

`platform.python_version_tuple()` is a tuple that is `('3', '11', '4')`. Due to the way tuple comparison works in python `('3', '11', '4') < ('3', '4')` evaluates to `True`. I would recommend:

1. Download [absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/53/9243c600e047bd4c3df9e69cfabc1e8004a82cac2e0c484580a78a94ba2a/absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz) from pypi
2. Extract the content, open the setup.py and comment the above mentioned lines
3. Run `python setup.py install` in the extracted directory

which manually disables this error.

**Note**
`rasa` - which you originally tried to install does not seem to be tested or doesn't support python 3.11, because its dependencies cannot be installed without manual work. It might still work, but more likely, you will have to downgrade your python version

Comment: And maybee go mock whoever doesn't update there dependencies for 'absl-py' since it's fixed a long time now https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/issues/161 ;)