Rasa install error Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required
these are my versions:
PS ...\Matteo> python --version Python 3.12.3 PS ....\Matteo> pip3 --version pip 24.2 from C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

I ran "pip3 install -U pip":
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (24.0) Collecting pip   Using cached pip-24.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB) Using cached pip-24.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB) Installing collected packages: pip   Attempting uninstall: pip     Found existing installation: pip 24.0     Uninstalling pip-24.0:       Successfully uninstalled pip-24.0 Successfully installed pip-24.2

After, when I need to install Rasa: "pip3 install rasa"
Collecting rasa
Using cached rasa-1.10.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Collecting PyJWT\<1.8,\>=1.7 (from rasa)
Using cached PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting SQLAlchemy\<1.4.0,\>=1.3.3 (from rasa)
Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.3.24.tar.gz (6.4 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting absl-py\<0.10,\>=0.9 (from rasa)
Using cached absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz (104 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[20 lines of output\]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip_vendor\\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in \<module\>
main()
File "C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip_vendor\\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out\['return_val'\] = hook(\*\*hook_input\['kwargs'\])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip_vendor\\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-iwsitz3e\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self.\_get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=\[\])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-iwsitz3e\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\build_meta.py", line 297, in \_get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-iwsitz3e\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\build_meta.py", line 497, in run_setup
super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
File "C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-iwsitz3e\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "\<string\>", line 34, in \<module\>
RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


I don't understand what I'm doing wrong!
I had unistalled all python versions and pip3, after I installed new version of python.
My OS is Windows and I clean C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python before to install new version of Python.
I expect to install Rasa on Py.

Looks similar to an old bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250610/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/76951307/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=absl-py+RuntimeError%3A+Python+version+2.7+or+3.4%2B+is+required
