# unable to install rtf via pip

Tags: python, pip, rtf

Trying to install rtf via pip and getting the below,

Have reinstalled Python and checked python and setuptools are UpToDate but still getting the same error.

```
`C:\Users\Dell>pip install rtf
  Collecting rtf
 Using cached rtf-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting absl-py==0.7.1 (from rtf)
  Using cached absl-py-0.7.1.tar.gz (99 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

 × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
 │ exit code: 1
 ╰─> [6 lines of output]
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
       File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v0_l0uum\absl-      py_cfabd528981b46f7aadc5bd0743d710e\setup.py", line 34, in <module>
       raise RuntimeError('Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.')
       RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
         [end of output]

   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 error: metadata-generation-failed

  × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
   ╰─> See above for output.
```

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`

Have reinstalled Python and checked python and setuptools are UpToDate but still getting the same error.

Comment: It says your Python version is not supported, that might be the reason. What is your Python version? You can check that by starting Python from the command line, then the version is printed at the top.

Comment: rtf pulls in absl-py package 0.7.1 and it has setup.py that triggers this error - its a *bug* in that specific version of absl ..  also fyi that for @Marijn

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250610/7976758